# How to Reorganize Displays Over Two GPUs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, display

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 with three total displays, one 16:9 on a GTX 1050Ti, and two 4:3 displays on a GT 520. It's working fantastic, except that when I go to move the location of the displays in the settings it goes all haywire and one display becomes black while staying connected. I have `@reboot root /sbin/modprobe nouveau` in my root crontab, and then I run `modprobe nouveau` once I login to get the two monitors on the GT 520 to start up. I also have the last three lines in /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf commented out.